# Convenient link to Area51 page?

Tags: support

From time to time I am curious how well the beta is doing. Each time I'm looking in vain for a link to the [Skeptics page on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics), before finally going to the main Area51 page and searching. Shouldn't there be a link from the Meta page to the Area51 page?

Answer (score 2):

It's already there on the main site.

Check the sidebar on the main site's left side:

[image]

Do you really need one for the meta, too?

Comment: No, I guess I was just looking for it in the wrong place. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: I rarely ever look at the default view.  For some reason this is hidden if you choose a view other than active.

Comment: The link is no longer part of the launched site layout. It's apparently just part of beta sites. However, now we don't need that link any longer, do we? At least not that often.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Exactly. Linking to Area51 only makes sense for beta site. Once a site graduates, it does not make much sense to care about when it will graduate. :)

Comment: Well, the statistic there is still interesting afterwards. As you can see we could improve some things like more questions and more answers per questions. Was there a count-down for the end of the beta? I checked this page actually this morning, when we were still in the beta phase, and didn't saw any. I was just wondering that it is already over one year in the beta phase.

Comment: @Martin: We were warned we were going out of beta on Febuary 10th. After that, it was mostly about finalizing our site's design because we had [some issues with it](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/skeptics-brand-concept-and-site-design).